# Averaging values across multiple hashes

Tags: ruby, hash, ruby-on-rails-4

**EDIT** I am accepting @CarySwoveland's answer because he got the closest on the first try, accounting for the most scenarios, and outputting the data into a hash so that you don't need to rely on order. Many honerable mentions though! Be sure to check out @ArupRakshit's answer as well if you want your output in an array!

I have an array of hashes like:

```
@my_hashes = [{"key1" => "10", "key2" => "5"...},{"key1" => "", "key2" => "9"...},{"key1" => "6", "key2" => "4"...}]
```

and I want an average for each key across the array. ie. `8.0,6.0...`

Note that the hashes all have the exact same keys, in order, even if the value for the key is blank. Right now this works:

```
<%= @my_hashes[0].keys.each do |key| %>
    <% sum = 0 %>
    <% count = 0 %>
    <% @my_hashes.each do |hash| %>
        <% sum += hash[key].to_f %>
        <% count += if hash[key].blank? then 0 else 1 end  %>       
    <% end %>
    <%= (sum/count) %>
<% end %>
```

but I feel like there may be a better way... any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
@my_hashes = [ {"key1"=>"10", "key2"=>"5"},
               {"key1"=>  "", "key2"=>"9"},
               {"key1"=> "6", "key2"=>"4"} ]

def avg(arr) arr.any? ? arr.reduce(:+)/arr.size.to_f : 0.0 end

(@my_hashes.each_with_object ( Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] } ) {
  |mh,h| mh.keys.each { |k| h[k] << mh[k].to_f unless mh[k].empty? } })
           .each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| h[k] = avg(v) }
  # => {"key1"=>8.0, "key2"=>6.0}
```

The object created by the first `each_with_object` is a hash whose default value is an empty array.  That hash is represented by the block variable `h`.  This means that if `h[k] << mh[k].to_f` is to be executed when `h.key?(k) => false`, `h[k] = []` is executed first.

One could alternatively drop the `avg` method and create a temporary variable before computing the averages:

```
h = @my_hashes.each_with_object ( Hash.new { |h,k| h[k]=[] } ) { |mh,h|
      mh.keys.each { |k| h[k] << mh[k].to_f unless mh[k].empty? } }

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = ( avg(v) arr.any? ? arr.reduce(:+)/arr.size.to_f : 0.0 }
```

Comment: Something about my real-life array is breaking this, even though it's working nicely for any `@my_hash` I throw at it, including if all `key1 => ""` or 0. I'm gonna try to trace the error

`undefined method `empty?' for nil:NilClass` at `mh[k].empty?`

Comment: Found it – not only must I account for `key1 => ""` but also for `key1 => nil`

Changed you solution to: `unless !mh[k] or mh[k].empty?` and it worked nicely... now to decide between yours or @ArupRakshit's answer...

Answer (score 2):

Do as below

```
@my_hashes = [{"key1" => "10", "key2" => "5"},{"key1" => "", "key2" => "9"},{"key1" => "6", "key2" => "4"}]
ar = @my_hashes[0].keys.map do |k|
   a = @my_hashes.map { |h| h[k].to_f unless h[k].blank? }.compact
   a.inject(:+)/a.size unless a.empty? #Accounting for "key1" => nil or "key1" => ""
end
ar # => [8, 6]
```

Comment: Thanks – I forgot to mention however, that the keys are variable as well, so I would need to do something like `@my_hash[0].keys.map do |k|` but it's breaking when it tries to divide:

`undefined method '/' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: @msanteler Each internal has has variable size of keys you mean ?

Comment: Each hash in the array will always have identical keys to one another, in both name and quantity – however, in any given use-case those names can be anything, and there can be any number of them.

Comment: Nice, Arup.  Glad to see you dealt with the missing values.

Comment: Arup, I noticed a couple of small problems.  I think you want `h[k].to_f`, rather than `to_i`, to allow for floats in the data (and also to make the averages floats).  Also, if, say, `"key1=>"0"` in all the hashes, you'd get a divide-by-zero exception when computing the average for `key1`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I did change it.. But I actually looked into the expected output of OP, which is not floating point numbers.

Comment: I edited the original post to reflect that I do, in fact, want floats and not integers – Would have been an easy change anyways though :)

I am actually running into the very problem @CarySwoveland is calling out when `keyn => ""` for all hashes. I like how clean this solution is, but I definitely need to account for all blanks

Comment: If I edit your solution to `a.inject(:+)/a.size unless a.empty?` it works nicely for all situations and is very clean. Thank you!

Comment: I'm still deciding between you and @CarySwoveland ;) You both have pretty different answers with different outputs, but both get the job done with their own strengths/weaknesses

Comment: @msanteler Your choice!! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a quite elegant solution.

Here is a sample array:

```
a = [
  {:a => 2, :b => 10},
  {:a => 4, :b => 20},
  {:a => 2, :b => 10},
  {:a => 8, :b => 40},
]
```

And the solution:

```
class Array
  def average
    self.reduce(&:+) / self.size
  end
end

r = a[0].keys.map do |key|
  [key, a.map { |hash| hash[key] }.average]
end

puts Hash[*r.flatten]
```

Comment: why `Hash[*r.flatten]` needed ?

Comment: Not *needed* but I assumed you wanted a single hash accounting the keys and their averages. :P

Comment: Note there are missing values.

Comment: This is beautifully simple, and would be very easy to make it take account of the ‘missing’ values – just need to modify the `average` method a bit. The only drawback is it only works if all keys are present in the first item.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@my_hashes = [{"key1" => "10", "key2" => "5"},{"key1" => "", "key2" => "9"},{"key1" => "6", "key2" => "4"}]

average_values = @my_hashes.map(&:values).transpose.map { |arr| 
    arr.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / arr.size 
}
with_keys = Hash[@my_hashes.first.keys.zip(average_values)]


average_values # =>  [5.333333333333333, 6.0]
with_keys # => {"key1"=>5.333333333333333, "key2"=>6.0}
```

if you want to exclude empty values from the average, could change average_values to reject empty values

```
average_values = @my_hashes.map(&:values).transpose.map { |arr| 
    arr.reject!(&:empty?)
    arr.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) / arr.size 
}

average_values # => [8.0, 6.0]
```

Comment: Nice solution. The data shown in the question clearly has missing values, so I would just show your second solution. A couple of points: depending on the order of pairs in hashes (though a given here) is generally not good practice; and you should allow for the possibility that one of the keys `=> ""` in all the hashes, resulting in `arr.size => 0`, which would raise a a divide-by-zero exception.

Answer (score 0):

No super clean solution, but I would write:

```
a = [
  {:a => 2, :b => 10},
  {:a => 4, :b => 20},
  {:a => 2, :b => 10},
  {:a => 8, :b => 40},
]

grouped = a.flat_map(&:to_a).group_by{|x,|x}

grouped.keys.each do |key|
  len = grouped[key].size
  grouped[key] = 1.0 * grouped[key].map(&:last).inject(:+) / len
end
```

Comment: Note there are missing values.